# C Database number output doesn't work

Tags: c, database, string, file, structure

Right so i have a piece of my code here that generates a database of usernames, passwords and scores perfectly, except that the scores do not allign with one another, This is clearly due to a problem with the string length function, I have tried to create temporary variable to store the values and few other garbage moves that only seem to make it worse.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void addscores(void);
void intmount(void);
FILE *faa; 
FILE *fab;
FILE *fac;
FILE *fu;
FILE *fp;
FILE *fs;
int temp;
int i3=0;
int DataCount=1;
int total=0;

struct store3
{
int def3;
}stock3[128];

int main()
{

    faa=fopen("Test 01 Scores.txt","r");
    fab=fopen("Test 02 Scores.txt","r");
    fac=fopen("Test 03 Scores.txt","r");


          struct store
          {
          char def[128];
          }stock[128];

          struct store2
          {
          char def2[128];
          }stock2[128];


         //int DataCount=1;
         int i=0;
         int i2=0;

         int tick;

         fu=fopen("Student Usernames.txt","r");
         fscanf(fu,"%127[^\n]%*c", stock[DataCount].def);
         for(i=0; stock[DataCount].def[i]!='\0'; ++i);

         fp=fopen("Student Passwords.txt","r");
         fscanf(fp,"%127[^\n]%*c", stock2[DataCount].def2);
         for(i2=0; stock2[DataCount].def2[i2]!='\0'; ++i2);

         addscores();
         //intmount();
         printf("|Username");
         printf("        |");
         printf("Password");
         printf("        |");
         printf("Total Score     |");
         printf("\n+----------------+----------------+----------------+\n");


         do
         {
                    printf("|%s", stock[DataCount].def);
                    i=16-i;
                    for(tick=0; tick<i;tick++)
                    {
                                printf(" ");
                    } 



                    printf("|%s", stock2[DataCount].def2);
                    i2=16-i2;
                    for(tick=0; tick<i2;tick++)
                    {
                                printf(" ");
                    } 


                    printf("|");

                    i3=16-i3;
                    for(tick=0; tick<i3;tick++)
                    {
                                printf(" ");
                    }
                    printf("%d|\n",total);

                    DataCount=DataCount+1;

                    fscanf(fu,"%127[^\n]%*c", stock[DataCount].def);
                    for(i=0; stock[DataCount].def[i]!='\0'; ++i);

                    fscanf(fp,"%127[^\n]%*c", stock2[DataCount].def2);
                    for(i2=0; stock2[DataCount].def2[i2]!='\0'; ++i2);

                    addscores(); //fscanf for scores
                    //intmount(); //char count for scores                  

    }
    while(!feof(fu));
    printf("|%s", stock[DataCount].def);
    i=16-i;
    for(tick=0; tick<i;tick++)
    {
                printf(" ");
    } 


    printf("|%s", stock2[DataCount].def2);
    i2=16-i2;
    for(tick=0; tick<i2;tick++)
    {
                printf(" ");
    } 
   // intmount();
    printf("|");
    i3=16-i3;
    for(tick=0; tick<i3;tick++)
    {
                printf(" ");
    }
    printf("%d|\n",total);


    DataCount=DataCount+1;

    fscanf(fu,"%127[^\n]%*c", stock[DataCount].def);
    for(i=0; stock[DataCount].def[i]!='\0'; ++i);


    fscanf(fp,"%127[^\n]%*c", stock2[DataCount].def2);
    for(i2=0; stock2[DataCount].def2[i2]!='\0'; ++i2);


    addscores();
    //intmount();


    fclose(faa);
    fclose(fab);
    fclose(fac);

    fclose(fu); 
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fs);
    getch();
}

void addscores(void)
{
total=0;
fscanf(faa,"%d", &stock3[DataCount].def3);
total=total+stock3[DataCount].def3;
fscanf(fab,"%d", &stock3[DataCount].def3);
total=total+stock3[DataCount].def3;
fscanf(fac,"%d", &stock3[DataCount].def3);
total=total+stock3[DataCount].def3;
}




void intmount(void)
{
for (i3 = 0; total!=0; i3++, total/=10){}
printf(" Number of digits: %d\n",i3);
}
```

Files consist of:

```
Pig
Sheep
Beef
Cat
Wolf

Pork
Wool
Beef
Fish
Bone

1
2
3
4
5

(for all 3 scores)
```

Before people start writing about my files or format or layout i know that there are probably a few things wrong like that but it's not a concern to me just yet, all i need is the spaces fixed, then i'll edit my perfected program to look nice.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop structure is messed up, you duplicate a whole bunch of code from inside the loop, before the loop. Just do it once in the loop, and don't use `while(!feof)`, that's almost always a mistake. Instead, check whether your `fscanf` calls succeed or not, and break out if they fail.

You code would be a whole lot more readable if you replaced the `for(i2` lines with calls to `strlen`, and didn't do it until you need it. I don't understand what `i3` is meant to be doing.

Regarding your spaces, you should use the `printf` justification options, e.g.

```
printf("%16s", foo);          // right-justified, print at least 16 chars
printf("%-16s", foo);         // left-justified, print at least 16 chars 
printf("%16.16s", foo);       // right-justified, print exactly 16 chars
printf("%-16.16s", foo);      // you can guess this one
```

You can use `""` instead of a variable name in those calls too.

If you still have trouble then post the actual output you are getting and explain how it differs from what you want to see.